# Connecting adjectives, "does not have to A and B"

Tags: grammar

The simplest things seem to be the hardest.

I am exercising the "does not have to be" structure.

If I want to say "the book does not have to be expensive", it is (may be?):

> 本は高くなくてもいいです。

But how do I say "the book does not have to be expensive and big"?

I [asked this in chat and got a kind answer](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/511/2015/3/11) from Xeo.

Xeo, thank you for your help and I hope I may quote you here:

> @saidy afaik, you generally connect adjectives with the て-form. So I'd wager it works here, too: 「本は高くなくて大きくなくてもいいです。」
>
> I may be totally wrong, though. Better wait until one of the gurus answer this :)

Is this the correct way to connect adjectives in this case?

Thank you for reading this far. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Yes, that is correct and beautiful Japanese.  the -て form is very flexible and can be used to connect adjectives as you have there.  When you are connecting verbs with successive -て forms then it adds a sense of "sequence."  Just as a learner's note (=

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the answer you got in chat is not quite right.

> 「[本]{ほん}は[高]{たか}くなくて[大]{おお}きくなくて**も**いいです。」

You would need to use 「も」 twice to make it grammatical.  You could say:

> 「本は高くなくて**も**、大きくなくて**も**いいです。」

The sentence is grammatical now, but it just does not sound very natural.  As a Japanese-speaker, I could ***not*** imagine someone saying this sentence in real life.  If it were a catch copy in advertisement (perhaps for e-books), it would sound pretty natural.

You could also say something like:

> 「本は高い[必要]{ひつよう}**も**なければ、大きい必要**も**ありません。」

Either way, you would need to use 「も」 twice.  It is as though you would need to use "n" twice in saying "**n**either A **n**or B".